# how to install and run PHPUnit + SeleniumRC On windows via Composer? and what if i need to add those package as Globle to access in all project

Tags: php, phpunit, composer-php, selenium-rc

I have XAMPP Configured in Windows machine, and Need to Install and Run PHPUnit_selenium Via Composer.
i have installed Composer Successfully and also Created json file With

```
"require":{
      "phpunit/phpunit-selenium": ">=1.2",
      "phpunit/phpunit": "4.8.*"
     }
```

and also Run **java -jar /usr/local/bin/selenium-server-standalone-2.*.*.jar**

and then try to Run **phpunit**  
so, Bottom line i can't reproduce Output as Given on doc of https://phpunit.de

Comment: You should specify what errors you get from the output

Comment: this error Found while i run my script: 
**argument #3 <No Value> of PHPUnit_TextUI_ResultPrinter::__construct() must be a value from 
"never","auto" or "always"**